# Laravel Nova Trix Field Call to Undefined Method Laravel/Nova/Fields/Trix::WithFiles()

Tags: laravel-nova

I have used field  `Trix::make('Biography')->withFiles('disks')`,
but It gives me following error

> Call to Undefined Method Laravel/Nova/Fields/Trix::withFiles() in Nova
>   Admin Panel

So how can I solve it.

Comment: What is your laravel nova version?

Comment: Check the case in `Laravel/Nova/Fields/Trix::WithFiles()` it must follow `camel case`  code format. It should be `withFiles`.

Comment: I have use Nova v1.0.8

Comment: @MaulikB There is a chance `withFiles` may added in after version 1.0.8. Did you try updating Nova to latest version

Comment: Thanks Saumini Navaratnam I have changed Nova version. Now its work.